# Make Telnet default to localecho ON

Tags: windows, telnet

Whenever I use `telnet` to connect to a system, one of the first things I do is:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>
- `set localecho`
- <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Is there a registry key or config file somewhere that I can change, so I don't have to do this anymore?

Comment: [A better Telnet client?](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)